# Amazon S3 as Backup

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm with a problem i need to implement a daily backup for my clients, i have an application for managing callcenters that work locally on the client, i have the database and application there, i need to do a daily backup in cloud, i'm considering S3, but i'm a little worried with security, since i'll need to create a AWS public account that can upload to S3 Bucket, and the account will be in the server, so if someone get the key they will be able to upload things, or flood the S3 Bucket, there is a safe way to do that?

I know that since the servers are in the client, basically it's hard to maintain security, but i'm trying to make things as hard as possible, to someone get or keys/access etc.

If there is any other service that i could use, it would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you read the AWS docs on Managing Access Permissions to S3 Resources http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html

You definitely do not need to create a public account with public access to your services. You can simply create a policy that limits the upload ability to whatever parameters you want. Then you upload that in the permissions of the bucket.

A sample bucket policy, limiting access to specific IAM users, who are connecting from specific IP addresses, and further limiting the upload to a specific file type (.zip) might look like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddCannedAcl",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root","arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"]}, 
      "Action":["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*.zip",
      "Condition":{
        "StringEquals":{"s3:x-amz-acl":["public-read"]},
        "IpAddress" : { "aws:SourceIp" : ["10.0.0.0/24", "192.168.0.9/32"] },

        }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above you'll change the following:

1. The list of IAM users under "Principal". You'll supplement those for the individual IAM users you create for each of your customers.
2. The name of your bucket and type of file under "Resource".
3. Finally you can whitelist IP addresses by using the "IpAddress" as shown in the  which is whitelisting the public IP address of the servers.

You could further limit the ability of the user to upload a file to a specific time of day (more complex, but it can be done). In this case the ability to upload would be limited to the specific IAM user, uploading a specific file-type, from a specific source IP address, at a specific time of day. IMO that's pretty tight upload restrictions for a backup. Since you're not giving anyone ability to download the files once they've been uploaded, I feel like this is a reasonable and robust level of security with the greatest risk being rogue uploads which would cost you storage fees; you can also setup alarms to notify you of suspicious activity. The point is that your scenario is seemingly low-risk and you can easily manage your requirements.

Finally, depending on how often you need access to the backup data you should consider using Glacier Vaults instead of S3 buckets... Glacier is substantially less expensive and is designed for data that needs to be accessed infrequently.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that exactly what i was looking for, with this restrictions i guess it will be fine, and i'll look at Glacier Vaults, i didn't know about it! And by the way, i'll read the docs haha

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for accepting it as the answer!